# Regex can't validate dates from 28 to 31

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, date, datetime

I have this regex to validate `dd/mm/yyyy`, `dd.mm.yyyy`, `dd-mm-yyyy`:
https://regex101.com/r/kO4rR8/1

and this to validate `hh:mm`:
https://regex101.com/r/oF6zB5/1

now I'm trying to concatenate the above expressions to validate `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm`, `dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm`, `dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm`:
https://regex101.com/r/rD9yM8/1

but I get a strange error... I can't validate dates from 28/mm/yyyy 00:00 to 31/mm/yyyy 00:00!

Can someone please help me to find out where is the problem?

Comment: Should `31/02/2016 00:00` be a valid date?

Comment: Mm... no... it shouldn't be a valid date; in fact, if you try `31/02/2016` here: https://regex101.com/r/kO4rR8/1 it doesn't validate, I was hoping to have the same result with `31/02/2016 00:00` too.

Comment: The regex in https://regex101.com/r/kO4rR8/1 is incorrect because it does not accept 29/02/2016 as valid. And the regex is too complex already; you really don't want to add more logic to it.

Answer (score 3):

Regex isn't the best bet for date validation. A very nice way to validate your dates is using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/), they have built in support for that.

```
function valiDate(ds) {
    let validDates = ["DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm", "DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm", "DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm"];
    return validDates.some(d => moment(ds, d).isValid())
}

console.log(valiDate("15.02.1985"));
console.log(valiDate("29.02.1985"));
console.log(valiDate("29.02.1985 00:00"));
```

Above will validate both with and without time - if you only pass a date (15.02.1985) it will validate correctly, too.

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/borgo28f/2)